# Imprimir a PDF archivos de manera automática por C# desde página web con frame

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, selenium-webdriver

Estoy intentando imprimir un archivo desde una dirección proporcionada, a partir de una consola de comandos. Sin embargo, estoy estancado en la parte de la descarga del archivo real, dado que la descarga se desencadena con un evento de Javascript al hacer click en un botón. Dado éste escenario y teniendo las direcciones, cómo puedo acceder al evento de Javascript dentro de la página con C# para hacer la descarga? Me sugirieron utilizar Selenium para realizar la tarea, sin embargo por el momento no sé cómo proceder a accionar el evento de Javascript asociado al botón, el cuál abre un cuadro de impresión de Chrome.

Los elementos para hacer click y desencadenar el cuadro de impresión como se ve en HTML:

```
<iframe style="border: none" height="30px" width="100%" name="primer_frame" id="primer_frame" src="AppToolBar?url=http://sitio.com/" scrolling="no" marginheight="0">
<html>
<head>
<iframe id="segundo_frame">
    <a href="javascript:printDocumentView()">Imprimir</a>
</iframe>
</head>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Mi código actual:

```
public static void Descarga(string url_inicial, string url_final) {

    var opciones = new ChromeOptions();
    opciones.AddArgument("--headless");    
    opciones.AddUserProfilePreference("print.always_print_silent", true);
    opciones.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
    opciones.AddUserProfilePreference("print.should_print_backgrounds", false);
    opciones.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.plugins_disabled", "Chrome PDF Viewer");
    var driver = new ChromeDriver(opciones);

    try{

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url_inicial);
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("primer_frame");
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("segundo_frame"); //acá el botón está

        var btn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/.../a")); //censurado a proposito
        btn.Click();

//El tema acá es, si hago click en el botón, me abre el cuadro de impresión
//de Chrome, pero cómo lo manejo, dada la característica del botón?

        PrintOptions print = new PrintOptions
        {

            Orientation = PrintOrientation.Portrait,
            OutputBackgroundImages = false,
            ShrinkToFit = true
                    
        };

        PrintDocument printd = driver.Print(print);
        printd.SaveAsFile(directorio_descarga + "\\" + "archivo.pdf");


        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        driver.Quit();
        driver.Dispose();

    }
    catch (Exception e){

        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        driver.Quit();
        driver.Dispose();

    }

}
```

Saludos y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que es por el frame. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

Comment: @Mateo intenté ver el tema del frame, pero no me lo detecta (no lo encuentra), a pesar de que existe sólo uno. Gracias de todas maneras

Comment: Ya pude resolver el tema del frame pero ahora tengo otra dificultad, así que actualicé la pregunta.

Comment: Tal vez no sea una solución deseable, pero si sabes dónde están los enlaces que querés descargar, podes obtenerlos y descargarlos directamente con C#.

Comment: Lamentablemente los enlaces son sólo los accesos a los documentos y necesito guardarlos en PDF. Imprimirlos desde el menú del navegador no me sirve, puesto que me imprimiría todo el contenido de la página (con los botones). Si hago click en el botón "imprimir" ubicado en el iframe, me despliega el cuadro de impresión del documento, pero sin los elementos  no deseados, sólo el documento limpio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final para poder solucionar mi requerimiento, decidí revisar el contenido que está dentro del iframe que contiene el documento que necesito imprimir y para mi suerte, era html y css solamente. Para ello, extraje el código del iframe con lo siguiente:

```
driver.PageSource;
```

Luego, después de revisar que el contenido era lo deseado, volqué el contenido hacía un archivo, el cuál luego abrí como si fuese a navegar a una nueva página web y procedí a imprimirlo (no sin antes configurar las opciones de impresión). Finalmente, eliminé el archivo previamente generado para crear la impresión del documento en PDF.